# Unity c# SceneManager LoadScene not running from Task.Delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this project, inside some code, a delay is started and then continued with `Debug.Log("Test");` and `SceneManager.LoadScene(...);`

(I have `using UnityEngine.SceneManager;`)

The whole thing looks like:

```
 Task.Delay(2).ContinueWith(t => { Debug.Log("Test"); SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name); });
```

What happens:

console prints "Test"
but scene is not starting. I also tested to load another scene but nothing happens.
Does anyone know if you can't load a scene from within a delay function?)

(No error is in console)

Comment: You can't use Threading in Unity like this. You should use a Coroutine instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a unity expert, but I see that async/await has been added, and so you can do what you want...kinda. You don't want to do it quite like you have it, though. I'm relying on knowledge of async/await more generally here...and ContinueWith will schedule the continuation under a default scheduler's control...and probably on a thread pool thread, and that's not what you want. In fact, I'll bet there's an exception happening that is getting swallowed by way you're doing it...and I'm guessing it's because you're not calling LoadScene on the primary thread. Instead, you can just do:

```
await Task.Delay( 2 );
Debug.Log("Test");
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

The way await works is that remainder of the code in the current method will get signed up as a continuation on the current thread. So you'll get the behavior you want: a 2 second delay followed by the remainder of the code.

Comment: Thanks really much, I'll try